# load component in browser ondemand/lazy loading

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-4, angular2-routing, angular4-router

What i'm looking for is loading the component in browser only if user navigate to particular link.
What i have in my project is 4 module's which are lazy-loaded.
Say that 1.Module A 2.Module B 3.Module C 4.Module D (Each Module have 5-6 component). 
As if we define our all component in NgModule declaration section,so if user navigate to Module B,all 6 component of Module B also loaded.
If i'm not wrong if my module have more then 20 component,it might create performance issue because browser  need to download all 20component all at once when the module is loaded.
so what i'm looking for is to Load the Module B with is bootstrap component but to load/download the rest of component in the browser only when user navigate to the particular link.

I'm using Angular 4 with MVC 5

Comment: Hi there, 1 question... You a looking a example of lazy loading ? Or it is teoreticaly question?)

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Comment: Here all info what you need to know about lazy loading

Comment: @NikolayZatonatskiy yes i'm looking for lazy loading but not only with module,but also with component. my goal is only to restrict the component in browser and download it my when i need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that using the **Dynamic Component Loader** mentioned in the Angular [docs](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader). Also you can check the live example [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qmajpgqoolk).

Comment: but i can't use this since my component are tied to url and will be loaded once the click on it.my concern is to just avoid this component to be loaded in browser when the NgModule is loaded instead i want to load the component when user navigate to it.